# Como colocar meu site programado em NodeJS no ar?

Tags: node.js

Sou programador PHP e utilizo o *FileZilla* para gerenciamento de arquivos, desta maneira, apenas colocando os arquivos dentro de uma pasta específica o servidor de hospedagem procura pelo arquivo *index* e sucesso.

No caso do *NodeJS*, inicio um servidor *localhost*, com o *listen* no arquivo principal, estou utilizando a engine de views *EJS*, ou seja, as paginas são renderizadas de acordo com a URL (`server.get('/', (req, res) => {})`) e não como arquivos HTML convencionais, segue uma imagem com a raiz do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como o servidor se comporta com essa estrutura, como e onde upar meu projeto, e, se precisarei trocar de hospedagem. (utilizo a hosgator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem muitas formas de você fazer isso, por isso não tem como eu colocar uma resposta ensinando um passo a passo aqui.

**Opção 1**

Você também pode utilizar o hostgator porém precisa ser um pacote VPS. Veja [Nodejs no hostgator](https://lab.hostgator.com.br/hc/pt-br/community/posts/360020807834-Node-js), você pode abrir um ticket que eles fazem a instalação para você.

**Opção 2**

Você também tem opções que tornam mais fácil o deploy, usando simplesmente o git como o [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) e [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/13/how-to-run-express.js-apps-with-netlify-functions/). Essas duas últimas contém diversos tutoriais de como fazer e é bem simples, basta configurar a parte do git e modificar umas opções no package.json que ele faz tudo automaticamente.

**Opção 3**

Porém se tratando de forma mais **manual**. Você pode utilizar o [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) para persistencia da sua aplicação, caso tenha algum erro ou algo do tipo ela não quebrar e o servidor cair.

O **Nodejs** por si só já agiria como um servidor... Da mesma forma que roda local, você só teria que deixar esse ip externo.

**Opção 4**

**Outra opção** é você colocar o node rolando local no servidor com o `PM2` e usar um .htaccess para redirecionar para aquele endereço local. Como você mexe com PHP deve estar acostumado com o `.htaccess`. O que você pode fazer é criar um rewrite nele, por exemplo

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/$1 [P,L]
```

Substitua os XXXXX com a sua porta que o server node está rodando. Que o redirect funcionaria. **Lembre-se de usar o PM2 para que quando ocorra uma excessão ou algo que quebre a aplicação, o servidor não cair.**

Comment: Legal! Mas por exemplo, eu tenho apache instalado no meu servidor onde rodo alguns sistemas em PHP. E ele roda em cima de um endereço (exemplo.net.br). Como eu faço para colocar minha API rodando em: api.exemplo.net.br ?

Comment: Você precisa configurar um DNS apontando para o seu ip do servidor rodando em nodejs